# Custom data annotation syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, data-annotations

I've created a custom data annotation to inform the user that a duplicate SKU has been entered.  The data annotation is as follows:

```
[Remote("doesSKUExist", "Products", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "SKU already exists. Please enter a different SKU.")]
public string SKU { get; set; }
```

In the ProductsController I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesSKUExist(string Sku)
    {
        string conStr = @"Data Source=cmsapirontech.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=CMSDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User ID=dwight;Password=Fatboy99!;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        SqlCommand does_SKU_exist = new SqlCommand("SELECT SKU FROM [Product] WHERE([SKU] = @SKU", sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        does_SKU_exist.Parameters.Add("SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Sku;
        var sku = does_SKU_exist.ExecuteScalar();
        return Json(sku == null);
    }
```

Currently, I am getting an error at line:

```
var sku = does_SKU_exist.ExecuteScalar();
```

"Incorrect syntax near @SKU"  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the `)` after the where clause, but actually there is no need for `(` and `)` in your case: the SqlCommand initialization should be like the following:

```
SqlCommand does_SKU_exist = new SqlCommand("SELECT SKU FROM [Product] WHERE [SKU] = @SKU", sqlconn);
```

You have to do a small change while adding parameter as well, that is :

```
does_SKU_exist.Parameters.Add("@SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Sku;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've been fighting with this darn thing all day.  It works now!

Comment: @DwightMendoza: Glad to hear that, Happy to help you